# React-native app with many images

Tags: android, react-native

Ive got a problem with react native app on android. It's like a gallery, so i need to show many images. First i'm  fetching data about urls of images, then i`m trying to render them. Almost all images are downloading, but not all of them. How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Some images are pretty big, but summary size of them less than 1 gb.

Before asking I was trying to launche app on my Samsung Galaxy s4 and emulated Galaxy s6. On emulated device situation is even more bad.

Comment: How you are downloading images from url ? Post your code here

Comment: I'm downloading only urls, then i'm doing somthing like this:
    `presetsToShow = presetsToShow.map((preset, i) => {
      const fullURL = URL + additionalUrl;
      return (
        <View
          key={preset.id + i}
          style={styles.category}
          type='dog'
        >
          <Image
            style={{ width: 88, height: 88 }}
            source={{ uri: fullURL }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    });`